# Suite Venezolana, I Registro by Antonio Lauro notations & fingerings [for classical (nylon strings) guitar]

Tags: notation, fingering, classical-guitar

As shown in the attached image,

(i) What do the numbers written in the circles indicate?

(ii)What do the numbers above the beams/below the "arm" notation indicate?

(iii) Does "arm" mean harmonic ?

I was thinking the numbers either mean which frets or which strings to play on, which  are usually indicated using roman numerals. If not, could they be the fingerings?

[image: Notation]

Comment: The circled numbers probably are string numbers, like in this question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/72873/circled-numbers-on-guitar-sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the harm (harmonics) for each note written refer to notes G B and E, the circled numbers tell which string each harmonic is played on. Tha numbers (12, etc.) are for the fretwire each string is touched over to play. Thus 1st note (G) 12th fret harmonic, 3rd string; 4th note (oct. G) again 3rd string, but 5th fret harmonic.

Comment: @Vehrnesto And yes, "arm" is missing the "h" probably because it's the Spanish *armónicas*

Comment: @AndyBonner - I assumed it was just out of shot. Or written by someone who 'drops their 'aitches'.  Brummies from the Midlands, England are infamous for that..!